# Ember child component updates parent component model only on click

Tags: javascript, ember.js, pikaday

I got this `form-component`, with a `datepicker` sub-component within, based on Pikaday.

In the `form-component` I've got an observer for `datepicker`'s value:

```
// form-component.hbs
{{date-picker value=model.dueDate}}


// form-component.js
testDueDate: function() {
  console.log(this.get('model.dueDate'));
}.observes('model.dueDate');

// date-picker.js
testDatepickerValue: function() {
  console.log(this.get('value'));
}.observes('value');

// Only triggers date-picker's observer, but not the one from form-component:
this.set('value', new Date());
```

When I manually pick a date (that is, opening the datepicker and clicking on any date with the mouse), everything works fine: both `testDueDate()` and `testDatepickerValue()` fire and display the given date.

But when I programatically set the date (that is, via Pikalendar API), the parent component's observer won't fire, even though the one in the datepicker do and shows `value` has changed.

By looking at Pikalendar's code I can see that both clicking on a date and programatically setting the date use the `setDate()` function, so, from there on, everything should trigger the same functions.

**Somehow, form component only updates `value` when calendar is clicked.**

Any ideas on what may I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you can share whole code if possible. From the description you had written it seems like it has to work; but somehow it is not.

Comment: @alptugd Let me see what would be the best way to share some functional code...

Comment: using observers like this is not a good idea. it will lead to code with lots of side effects that is basically impossible to debug. using computed properties or closure actions for inter-component communication would be better. the ember core team's official guidance is to consider observers a framework primitive only to be used internally within Ember. if you post more of your code we can suggest a better way to structure it

Comment: @ChristopherMilne I'm not actually using them, It's just test code for debugging, but thanks for your input.